# Nice way to replace multiple strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

is there any way to do the next lines of code more elegant in javascript? Basically I am trying to replace any occurrence of `{{` or `}}` with empty string. Here is what I use now:

```
tmp = "{{ some_text }}"
tmp = tmp.replace(/{{/g , "");
tmp = tmp.replace(/}}/g , "");
tmp = tmp.trim();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OR in the regex

```
tmp = "{{ some_text }}";
tmp = (tmp.replace(/{{|}}/g, "")).trim();
```

Comment: Do you need the extra parentheses?

Comment: @Popnoodles - not really, just added them to make it "clearer", at least I thought so !

Answer (score 2):

This one handles the whitespace as well:

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/{{\s*|\s*}}/g, '')
"some_text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below,

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/{{|}}/g , "");
tmp = tmp.trim();
```

In regex `|` symbol means logical OR operator.